# SQL inner join 3 tables with same key

Tags: sql, inner-join

I want to try to join 3 tables together they all use the same key called `ITEM_NO` item number. I might actually need to add one more table as well called "USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP" would that also be a inner join?

Tables are `dbo.IM_PRC`, `dbo.IM_ITEM`, `dbo.IM_INV_CELL` sorry for being a noob!

```
SELECT     dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO, dbo.IM_PRC.LOC_ID, dbo.IM_PRC.DIM_1_UPR, 
dbo.IM_PRC.DIM_2_UPR,dbo.IM_PRC.DIM_3_UPR, dbo.IM_PRC.REG_PRC,dbo.IM_PRC.PRC_1, dbo.IM_PRC.PRC_2, dbo.IM_ITEM.CATEG_COD, dbo.IM_ITEM.SUBCAT_COD, dbo.IM_ITEM.STAT, dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO, dbo.IM_ITEM.IS_ECOMM_ITEM, dbo.IM_ITEM.VEND_ITEM_NO,dbo.IM_ITEM.LST_COST,dbo.IM_ITEM.USER_MAG_NAME,  dbo.IM_INV_CELL.LOC_ID,dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_2_UPR, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_3_UPR, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.MIN_QTY,dbo.IM_INV_CELL.MAX_QTY, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.QTY_ON_HND,   


 FROM dbo.IM_PRC 
 INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM ON dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO 
 INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL ON dbo.IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO


    WHERE     (dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'tum')
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: While it may not be needed for so simple a query, it's good always to tag which specific implementation of SQL (RDBMS) you are using: SQL Server, PostGreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeat `JOIN` for each separate table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IM_PRC 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM ON dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL ON dbo.IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO
WHERE     (dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'X')
```

I recommend using aliases and removing unnecessary parentheses too:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IM_PRC P
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM I ON P.ITEM_NO = I.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL IC ON IC.ITEM_NO = P.ITEM_NO
WHERE I.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'X'
```

Comment: +1 for adding the cleaned up version. And, for the sake of completeness, the OP should replace SELECT * with an explicit list of the fields that are really needed by the query.

Comment: I got a error hmm Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'


FROM dbo.IM_PRC 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM ON dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL ON dbo.IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO

WHERE     (dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'tum')

Comment: @user2679634 Did you include the `SELECT`?

Comment: Yup I just posted the full thing below thanks for the help!

Comment: @johnny NP - It looks like you have an extra comma at the end of your `SELECT` list, before your `FROM`.  Delete that comma and try again

Comment: that was it! wow also I just asked "I might actually need to add one more table as well called "USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP" would that also be a inner join?" so that would be INNER JOIN dbo.USER_MAG_ITEM_EXP ON dbo.USER_MAG_ITEM_EXP.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRICE.ITEM_NO right?

Comment: @johnny Compare the table name in the error/last join to the table name in your `FROM` ;)

Comment: @AaronDietz ALL SET YOU ARE THE BEST!

Comment: @AaronDietz hey aaron this is old but I have a bunch of duplicate rows and the new table I inner joined does seem to match up correctly.

Comment: @johnny Hey Johnny, hmm.. What does "not matching up correctly" mean?  I'll try to help but you might be better off asking another question with sample data, current results, expected results

Comment: @AaronDietz here is a screenshot of my current code it has 288 rows and the SKU(usr_mg_item_exp.sku) doesn't match the other two tables https://ibb.co/gmOQ89

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM IM_PRC ip 
INNER JOIN IM_ITEM ii ON ip.ITEM_NO = ii.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN IM_INV_CELL iic ON ip.ITEM_NO = iic.ITEM_NO 
     WHERE ii.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'X'
```

You can use LEFT or RIGHT joins if you need all details from either of tables instead of INNER.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the 3 table explicitally

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IM_PRC 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM ON dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL ON  dbo.IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO
     AND  dbodbo.IM_INV_CELL.M_VEND_NO = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below

```
Select * 
From dbo.IM_PRC PRC
Inner join dbo.IM_ITEM ITEM ON PRC. ITEM_NO = ITEM. ITEM_NO
Inner join dbo.IM_INV_CELL CELL ON PRC. ITEM_NO = CELL. ITEM_NO
WHERE ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'X'
```